# Use LINQ to concatenate multiple rows list with same value into single row

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, linq-to-objects

Group the repetitive value in the object list using Linq query.

I have the following data as table called "SudentAssessment" with these data.

```
AssessmentId    Username        SITSupervisor    WorkSupervisor
1              iwsp.student001  iwsp.staff001   iwsp.supervisor001
2              iwsp.student001  iwsp.staff002   iwsp.supervisor001
3              iwsp.student002  iwsp.staff001   iwsp.supervisor002
4              iwsp.student003  iwsp.staff003   iwsp.supervisor003
5              iwsp.student004  iwsp.staff001   iwsp.supervisor004
6              iwsp.student004  iwsp.staff005   iwsp.supervisor004
7              iwsp.student005  iwsp.staff003   iwsp.supervisor005
```

Here the issue is row number 1,2 and 5,6 having same data but only difference is SIT supervisor detail is different. These each rows populated into StudentAssessmentDTO which looks like below.

```
public class StudentAllocationDTO
{
     public int AssessmentId {get;set;}
     public string Username {get;set;}
     public string SITSupervisor {get;set;}
     public string WorkSupervisor {get;set;}
}
```

As per the current implementation I when call a method that returns List with all 7 records. as row 1,2 and 5,6 has more only difference in "SITSupervisor" I want to assign to the below DTO structure using LINQ in c#.

```
public class NEWStudentAllocationDTO
{
     public int AssessmentId {get;set;}
     public string Username {get;set;}
     public List<string> SITSupervisor {get;set;}
     public string WorkSupervisor {get;set;}
}
```

If you anyone need further clarification please let me know in the comment.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is the result you are expecting? you want to group them?

Comment: If you take the rows 1 and 2. Which AssessmentId should be taken? What should happen if the WorkSupervisor differs for the same student?

Comment: You can use `.GroupBy(c => new {AssessmentId = c.AssessmentId, Username = c.Username})`. After grouping you can loop through the items and instanciate your NEWStudentAllocationDTO

Comment: @Oliver AssessmentId will not be an issue here. I want to populate the results to just to showcase in the Jquery table.

Comment: `AssessmentId` is an issue, cause it is an property of your `NewStudentAllocationDTO` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group them by an anonymous type containing the common properties.

```
        IEnumerable< NEWStudentAllocationDTO> grouped = l.GroupBy(x => new { x.Username, x.WorkSupervisor })
            .Select(x => new NEWStudentAllocationDTO()
            {
                AssessmentId = x.Key.AssessmentId,
                WorkSupervisor = x.Key.WorkSupervisor,
                Username = x.Key.Username,
                SITSupervisor = x.Select(y => y.SITSupervisor).ToList()
            });
```

Comment: You should remove the AssessmentId from the anonymous type. Otherwise nothing will be grouped (according to the given example data).

Comment: This is true. I left it as I was wondering that the type NEWStudentAllocationDTO also contains such field, not as list. EDIT2: I remove it.

Comment: That was my biggest issue, too.

Comment: @Malior just understood what was requested reading your answer, the `x.Select(y => y.SITSupervisor).ToList()` may return the list of SITSupervisors as I understood? Interesting I didn't know it was possible :)

Comment: Thanks @Malior for the answer. It works well for me.